# Why could Snape be heard in Grimmauld Place?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, severus-snape, order-of-the-phoenix

In the early part of *Order of the Phoenix* the Order is having a meeting, talking about Harry. We can hear Snape but when everyone else comes down to eat Snape is the only one who isn't there. So why did we hear him?

Comment: It would be better if your could point out the exact meeting of the Order. The first meeting when Harry arrived at 12 Grimauld place, the second one, or the one during the Christmas break.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a question based on the movie, not the book?

Comment: I've edited the question to try and make it clearer. If it's changed the meaning or I've not understood your question do feel free to rollback or edit.

Comment: @TheDarkLord well, it wasn't mentioned clearly, so i assumed it be the book.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the scene isn't that well done in the movies in my opinion, and I suppose there could be some interesting conference calling magic going on. in fact, you know, snape's relationship to the order, his aloofness from it, his refusal to eat dinner at Grimmauld Place is drawn out a bit more in the books and is interesting and is relevant. In the movies it is an unexplored point which I think makes this question non-trivial +1

Answer (score 8):

Well, I'd suggest you to read the book again. Because Snape was there and the trio- Harry, Ron and Hermione saw him during the meeting (actually caught a glimpse of him as it were). Fred and George tell everyone about Snape being at the meeting that day

> Fred heaved a deep sigh. “Shame. I really fancied finding out what
>   old Snape’s been up to.”
>
> “Snape?” said Harry quickly. “Is he here?”
>
> “Yeah,” said George, carefully closing the door and sitting down on
>   one of the beds; Fred and Ginny followed. “Giving a report. Top
>   secret.”
>
> “Git,” said Fred idly.

Once they are summoned for dinner, the trio actually catch a glimpse of Snape sitting at the centre of the table:

> “Yeah, yeah,” said Ron. “C’mon, I’m starving.”
>
> He led the way out of the door and onto the landing, but before
>   they could descend the stairs — “Hold it!” Ron breathed, flinging out
>   an arm to stop Harry and Hermione walking any farther. “They’re
>   still in the hall, we might be able to hear something —”
>
> The three of them looked cautiously over the banisters. The gloomy
>   hallway below was packed with witches and wizards, including all of
>   Harry’s guard. They were whispering excitedly together. ***In the very
>   center of the group Harry saw the dark, greasy-haired head and prominent
>   nose of his least favorite teacher at Hogwarts, Professor Snape.***
>   Harry leaned farther over the banisters. He was very interested in what
>   Snape was doing for the Order of the Phoenix.

After which,

> They heard the front door open and then close.
>
> “Snape never eats here,” Ron told Harry quietly. “Thank God. C’mon.”

So, Snape was there and he was also seen.

Comment: I meant in the movie, I can't seem to see snape around the table anywhere. Obviously I know he was there as we can hear him etc but I was just wondering why we never get to see him.

Comment: Same reason as in the book - he was there but has left by the time they get to the table.  Only difference is that in the book Harry happens to see him as he is on the way out.